# Mlflow tutorial issue

Tags: python, anaconda, mlflow

I am trying [this quickstart tutorial](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/quickstart.html) but I have troubles with the serving phase

I issued the command

```
         mlflow models serve -m runs:/c94c36bb6c0c48a2a7c895d93ec1866f/model
```

I get the following

```
2020/05/06 14:04:33 INFO mlflow.models.cli: Selected backend for flavor 'python_function'

2020/05/06 14:04:35 INFO mlflow.projects: === Creating conda environment mlflow 4133253245e67fa1d3bbd74212a1eb60c04fbc0a ===

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:

scikit-learn=0.22.2.post1
```

It seems conda cannot find this version of scikit-learn

I have installed https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh

Please help me,

Aurel

Comment: What is your `sklearn` version?

Comment: It seems not to be installed ...

Comment: Do you use any type of virtual environments??

Comment: It seems not be installed ...

I run connda install sklearn and I get ..

....

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - sklearn


Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

...

What's your suggestion?

Comment: Yes , I used venv ...

Comment: conda update sklearn

PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /home/aurel/anaconda3/envs/myenv376
  package name: sklearn

Comment: I have not installed sklearn ... there is not on the current channels enumerated upper
There is a posibillity to install from pypy (or from else where)?

Comment: run `pip install sklearn==0.22.2`

Comment: It desn't work ...

pip install sklearn==0.22.2

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sklearn==0.22.2 (from versions: 0.0)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for sklearn==0.22.2

Comment: I think you need the conda-forge channel to get `scikit-learn=0.22.2.post1` - I guess `conda config --add channels conda-forge` should solve your problem.

Comment: @aurel _Yes , I used venv..._ Aren’t you using Conda? Please share the contents of the environment. By the way, there appears to be a Conda package for MLflow: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mlflow.

Comment: @AMC , it was my mistake, I don't need venv

Comment: Are you using Conda, though? That part still isn't clear.

Comment: I don't use mlflow anymore